# Does ROS support ethernet IP, Profibus and Profinet?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just starting to know the Industrial version of ROS  and could not find any documentation whether ROS supports industrial standard communication protocols. If yes please provide any documentation and if no please help me understand the concept behind it. Any alternative can also be a good start off.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260332/does-ros-support-ethernet-ip,-profibus-and-profinet?/) by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2017-04-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-26**:
Are you looking for support to communicate *between* ROS nodes using industrial fieldbuses, or just support to communicate with PLCs and other supporting equipment?

**Comment by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) on 2017-04-26**:
Basically, both but preferably to communicate PLCs and other supporting equipment over Fieldbus via ROS as two PLC's direct communication over fieldbuses is always possible.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-26**:
Using a fieldbus as the physical / transport layer for the ROS middleware would probably not make much sense: most fieldbuses employ memory-synchronisation schemes, with memory divided up into words with addresses associated to them. While possible to use those as a generic storage pool, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-26**:
.. it would probably not really work very well / be limited, as PLCs and other industrial hw would not be able to properly process the higher-level abstractions that ROS typically employs.

The pkgs/nodes that @Andre Volk linked to would probably be a more suitable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK ROS does not natively support any of the listed proprietary industrial protocols.
But you can find some previous work on bridging between ROS and industrial protocols, like [EtherCAT](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Simple_EtherCAT_Network_IO). Here is a nice collection of [ROS bridges](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2016/2/23/ros-bridges-for-common-field-busses) to several industrial field busses.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) on 2017-04-26**:
That was helpful thank you Andre. I shall try to find out the results and post it back.

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-04-26**:
I am glad to hear, that you like my answer. If you think, that I answered your question correctly, please  click on the check mark.